# Makefile leaves .o and doesn't produce executable

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a problem with a makefile I made, which products no executable and leaves all .o in the directory. Here is the code :

```
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall

    sources = tst_Robot.cpp Robot.cpp Position.cpp Plot.cpp Objet.cpp EtatRobot.cpp EtatFige.cpp EtatEnRoute.cpp EtatEnChargeFacePlot.cpp EtatEnCharge.cpp EtatAVideFacePlot.cpp EtatAVide.cpp
    objets = $(sources:.cpp=.o)

    %: %.o
           $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $^

    robot : $(objets)

    ###

     clean:
            rm -f *~ *.o *.bak

    depend:
            makedepend $(sources)
```

What I don't understand is that the makedepend works, there is no error, all the .o are produced, but the program itself is not produced, even with the rule : 
         robot : $(objets)

So I don't understand why it doesn't work, and I would be grateful if you could help me figurint it out.

Comment: `%: %.o` would only work for a single `.o` file.

Comment: why ? I thought that the % was selecting all the files ended by ".o"

Comment: The root of dependency tree is the traget you `make`. Since `make depend` will call to `makedepend $(sources)` only `$(sources)` will be made, while running `make robot` should obviously will create the executable.

Comment: You have not give us the complete makefile, so we cannot be sure. What happens if you add the `$(LINK.cpp) ...` command to the `robot` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern rules are always for one to one matches of pairs of files, e.g.

```
%.o: %.cpp
```

You may think of that a pattern rule is just a shortcut for writing a separate rule for each pair.
The above rule would match following pairs:

```
source.o: source.cpp
other.o: other.cpp
...
```

What you need is to put the rule how to make `robot` where the robot target is going to be made.

```
robot: $(objets)
       $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $^
```

And you have to remove the pattern rule as it applies to almost everything.
If you would call make using:

```
make robot
```

The pattern rule would try to find a `robot.o` file which would be the input to build robot.